# Running pywin32 COM object as another user

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I have a Python program using COM objects that I'd like to run remotely. That program runs well on the local machine, but when I run the program on a remote machine and try to use DCOM objects to remotely connect to the COM object on the remote machine, NTLM authentication fails (seen in a Wireshark capture).

The machine is on a Windows domain, but I can create as many local user on both machine as I like. I've tried creating the same local user on both machine, but the DCOM object is passing the machine as the domain (i.e trying to authenticate to `Machine2` with `Machine1\user`).

Any advice?

**Is there a way with `pythoncom` or `win32com` to specify a different user and password to use for NTLM authentication?**

I'm more than willing to answer any questions and add as many details as I possibly can.

Code:

```
print "\nConnecting to '%s'" % LAHostNameOrIP ;
try:
    LAConnect = win32com.client.Dispatch("AgtLA.Connect")
    # Fails on the LAConnect.GetInstrument call
    LAInst = LAConnect.GetInstrument(LAHostNameOrIP)
except pythoncom.com_error, (hr, msg, exc, arg):
    print "The AgtLA call failed with code: %d: %s" % (hr, msg)
    if exc is None:
        print "There is no extended error information"
    else:
        wcode, source, text, helpFile, helpId, scode = exc
        print "The source of the error is", source
        print "The error message is", text
        print "More info can be found in %s (id=%d)" % (helpFile, helpId)
    sys.exit(1)
```